# Perl, Help understanding Class declaration code

Tags: perl

I am creating a class, and I am trying to understand the following code

```
sub new {
    my ($class, %ar) = @_;

    return bless \%ar, $class;
}
```

I am specifically looking at the code inside of the block.

```
my($class, %ar) = @_;
```

I know that %ar are the arguments passed to the class, but i do not understand what this statement means.

Can someone explain what this code means and what it does?

Comment: Where exactly do you have problems understanding? Does reading [bless](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/bless.html) help?

Comment: @Corion - Sorry, I have updated my question.

Answer (score 4):

`@_` contains the arguments of the subroutine. If you call

```
my $object = My::Class->new( x => 7, y => 12 );
```

(which is the most common way to call a constructor) the subroutine `My::Class::new` will be called with five arguments:

```
'My::Class', 'x', 7, 'y', 12
```

so `$class` will become 'My::Class' and `%ar` will contain two keys, `x` with the value of 7, and `y` with the value of 12.

[bless](http://p3rl.org/bless) will then associate the reference to `%ar` with the class, i.e. make it an object of the class. The object will therefore be a reference like

```
{ x => 7, y => 12 }
```

blessed to `My::Class`.

The syntax `Class->method` is similar to calling an instance method

```
$object->proceed($z);
```

when the `proceed` subroutine will be called with two arguments, `$object` and `$z`. What class the subroutine comes from depends on what class the `$object` has been blessed to (i.e. it could be the `$object`'s class or its parent or its grandparent...)

Comment: ++ It may be useful to expand on the arguments to the `new()` call, by adding a second key/value pair, as well as a brief explanation that once the class has been shifted off, all of the other items (comma-separated list) are put into the hash that's then blessed.

Comment: I would add a comment on why the package name (`My::Class`) is there, and that in non-OO code it isn't.  This is in fact not mentioned anywhere on this page and may confuse readers.  (It could be what the question is about?)